# C# base class extension is called instead of the one for a derived class

Tags: c#, generics

I have class A which is a base class for B. And an extension for both types. Then if I call an extension from a generic function (even with an object of type B) it still calls an extension for a base class

```
void Main()
{
    var b = new B();
    
    GenericClass.SomeGenericFunction<B>(b);
}

public class A
{
    public void fooA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
};

public class B : A
{
    public void fooB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
};

public static class Extension {
    public static void SomeMethod(this A a)
    {
        a.fooA();
    }
    
    public static void SomeMethod(this B b)
    {
        b.fooB();
    }
};

public static class GenericClass {
    public static void SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new()
    {
        someObject.SomeMethod();
    }
};
```

The question basically is why the result is?

```
A
```

Comment: because you are telling here its of type A . where T : A . IN the code line :  public static void SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new()

Comment: @AmjadSaab I think SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new() means T is A or it has A as a base class

Comment: Generic method for reference types shares implementation for all reference types so  compiler will resolve `SomeMethod` only one time - for "highest" class in hierarchy - `A`.

Comment: @GuruStron is there any walkaround for this?

Comment: @NikitaAznauryan yes - by making `SomeMethod` instance method of `A` hierarchy or using type testing/casting in the generic method.

Comment: @GuruStron sorry did not get it. Can you please share the code?

Comment: @GuruStron ah, got it. Unfortunately, I can't change class A, it is an auto-generated class which I cna't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic method for reference types shares implementation for all reference types so compiler will resolve `SomeMethod` only one time during compilation - for "highest" class in hierarchy - `A`. You can workaround that either by changing `A` (and `B`) by making `SomeMethod` an virtual instance method of `A` hierarchy or using type checks in your generic function:

```cs
public static class GenericClass 
{
    public static void SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new()
    {
        switch (someObject)
        {
            case B b:
                b.SomeMethod();
                break;
            case A:
            default:
                someObject.SomeMethod();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or diving into reflection.

Comment: @NikitaAznauryan was glad to help! Also if you have control over generator - you can make your classes [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) and then you should be able to extend their functionality as needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
};

public class B : A
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
};

public static class Extension
{
    public static void SomeMethod(this A a)
    {
        a.foo();
    }

    public static void SomeMethod(this B b)
    {
        b.foo();
    }
};

public static class GenericClass
{
    public static void SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new()
    {
        someObject.SomeMethod();
    }
};
```

test

```
   var b = new B();

    GenericClass.SomeGenericFunction<B>(b);
```

result

```
B
```

if you need to keep your classes, you can use this code as well. It is easier to extend and mantain. I only don't understand why do you need extensions if you use GenericClass? Maybe it is easier to use as C bellow? Or just use extensions. It seems as they repeat each other.

```
public static class GenericClass 
{
    public static void SomeGenericFunction(B someObject) 
    {
        someObject.SomeMethod();
    }
public static void SomeGenericFunction(C someObject) 
    {
        someObject.fooC();
    }
    public static void SomeGenericFunction<T>(T someObject) where T : A, new()
    {
        someObject.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't change the classes and they have different functions fooA and fooB rather than foo()

Comment: @NikitaAznauryan You should post it in your question.  I updated my answer according to this new information.