# Null object not being null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the following function to have a handy utility for sanity checks in my unity projects.

```
namespace MyProject.Utilities
{
    public class DebugUtils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if passed object is null and prints to console if it is.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
        public static void DebugAssertNull<T>(T obj, string tag = "M_UTILS_DEBUG")
        {
            if (obj == null) 
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new();
                StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
                string methodName = stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
                string fileName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
                int lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
                string message = $"[{tag}] Object of type {typeof(T)} is null in method {methodName} at {fileName}:{lineNumber}";
                UnityEngine.Debug.Assert(false, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I call this function from another script as follows

```
public class SomeBehaviour: MonoBehaviour{
    public GameObject someObject;
    
    void Start(){
        DebugAssertNull<GameObject>(someObject);
    }

}
```

Now I am expecting that a message prints to the console. However upon running this code obj turns out to be not null. Using the debugger in Visual Studio 2019, setting up a watch  `obj == null` evaluates to true.

I feel like there is some implementation detail I am missing here. I am working with unity 2021, Visual Studio 2019, and .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Maybe == is overloaded for your type. check via `if(obj is null)` to be sure the variable is really null.

Comment: Tried it got the same result. The debugger shows that == null evaluates to true but the code doesn't? Where am I being stupid?

Comment: @SomeBody the issue was that it did basically that and went for `System.Object == System.Object` ... but Unity have their own custom operator overload for `UnityEngine.Object == UnityEngine.Object` which apparently is skipped due to the method using generics. Especially since the field is serialized in the Inspector the serializer already instantiates .. something ^^ But it throws a custom `Unassigned` exception instead of just being actual `null`

Comment: IIRC Unity does some awful stuff in its `==` overload. I've not got time to write a whole answer, but if you do `gameObj is null`, you should get what you want

Comment: @ScottishTapWater as far as I understand OP wants the Unity behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76225277/7111561).

Since your method uses generics without any type limitation it will use the most generic `==` implementation which is for `System.Object`.

It works as expected if you explicitly limit the type like e.g.

```
public static void DebugAssertNull<T>(T obj, string tag = "M_UTILS_DEBUG") where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    if (obj == null) 
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new();
        StackFrame stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
        string methodName = stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
        string fileName = stackFrame.GetFileName();
        int lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
        string message = $"[{tag}] Object of type {typeof(T)} is null in method {methodName} at {fileName}:{lineNumber}";
        UnityEngine.Debug.Assert(false, message);
    }
}
```

This way it definitely uses the overload `UnityEngine.Object ==`.

If this is intended to be used for stuff referenced in the Unity Inspector it should also be enough.

The only thing going by reference in the Inspector **is** `UnityEngine.Object`. Everything else is deserialized as values directly and never `null`.

Question would then be though why have such a debug tool for this case instead of simply checking directly

```
private void Start()
{
    if(!someObject) Debug.LogError($"{nameof(someObject)} is not assigned", this);
}
```

advantage of this would be:

- Double click on the log message and directly jump to according code line
- Click once on the message highlights according object in the Hierarchy (or the assets)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just writing it as a curiosity. I understand there are better methods to do this.

Comment: @PiyushDivyankar In vanilla .NET generics are compiled only one time for reference types to prevent "code bloat" so for operators resolutions T is the most common denominator - `object`. [Here is another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70932116/2501279) with the same source issue.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for backing this up with more background info!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old Unity... hmm... let's call it a "feature" =)

The reason is that real Unity objects are in the C++ part and C# objects are only wrappers for these objects. That's why the basic Unity3d object overrides `==` operator and returns `true` in case of comparing with null even object still exists.

You can find more [information here](https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)

Comment: this is true and especially confusing in context where it might go for `System.Object` equality rather than using the `UnityEngine.Object` overload (e.g. for `?.` , `??` etc operators!) .. and even more for Inspector serialized fields ^^ ... in this case here I would expect though that `T = GameObject` .. so shouldn't it still go through the `UnityEngine.Object` overload and behave as expected?

Comment: So I understand that if Object is unassigned it can't be null. Is there a way to check if an object is unassigned cheaply?